# H2 database - file mode

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

Is it possible to keep your h2 database in file instead of memory? Now my JDBC URL is: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb. I would like to keep the h2 database in file. I want my JDBC URL to be something like that: jdbc:h2:file:./data/sample. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, just do `jdbc:h2:/file/path`.

More information here: http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html